# NLog: Adding Parameters at Action level for Asp.Net Core

Tags: logging, parameters, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, nlog

Hi I am using Nlog according to  [this](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-(project.json)) and I created a custom layout in addition. In my Action I want to pass parameters to the `Ilogger` that i can use in my custom layout. In my controller action i have

```cs
var theEvent = new LogEventInfo(NLog.LogLevel.Debug, "", "");
theEvent.Properties["MyValue"] = "My custom string";
_logger.LogInformation("Index page says hello ", theEvent, 1, "two", 3.2);
```

But when i debug the custom layout, the parameter list is null. The parameters are not added to the property list either. What am i doing wrong here

```cs
[LayoutRenderer("hello-universe")]
public class HelloUniverseLayoutRenderer : LayoutRenderer
{
    protected override void Append(StringBuilder builder, LogEventInfo logEvent)
    {       
        builder.Append("hello I am custom layout");
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Currently the only working way is to use the non-DI loggers for this.

```cs
var logger = LogManager.GetLogger(YourController.GetType().FullName); //recommend as static field in your class

var theEvent = new LogEventInfo(NLog.LogLevel.Info, "", null, "your message with param {0}", "param1");
theEvent.Properties["MyValue"] = "My custom string";
logger.log(theEvent);
```